# Get gravity forms input values

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

How do i get the values of specific input elements inside the `gform_after_submission` hook in [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/)?
I can get the labels with

```
foreach($form['fields'] as $k=>$v)
{
    $label=$form['fields'][$k]['label'];
}
```

but how do I get the values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the Gravity guidelines you set up the hook to call your own function - in the case below the function is after_submission().

You can access the input values of individual form elements using their IDs like so;

```
add_action("gform_after_submission", "after_submission", 10, 2);

function after_submission($entry, $form){

    $name = $entry["2"];
    $address = $entry["17"] . ', '. $entry["18"] .', '. $entry["19"];

}
```

The IDs are all there in the form fields title in the backend, just hover over each one and it'll give you the type and ID (ie 'Single Line Text: Field ID 2).

http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_after_submission